# Where to put my Struct to keep classes independent?

Tags: swift, struct

I have a class which I want to be reusable (for any developer user who wants it, or outside my project). This class returns a `Struct`, let's call it `structA`, and the class is `classA`.

The first thought is to put `structA` inside the same **file** of this class, so while the `Struct` is public, any user who get this class file can read this `Struct` which the class returns.

Till here it looks reasonable (or not).

But what happens if other classes in my current project also need to use this `Struct` for other purposes? (a copy of it)

Then to make the code reusable I need to put this struct somewhere else. By reusable I mean there are no dependencies- get the class file and that is it.

If it's outside `classA`, then `classA` becomes *not reusable* and dependent.

If it's inside `classA`, then other class that use it are also dependent (not reusable outside)

The only solution left is to create other Structs like this with different names (sounds bad).

Where would you put this `Struct` in your Xcode project?

Comment: What is your proposed distribution method / format? Files on github? Pod? Framework? Library?

Comment: Thanks, assuming I just want to write code more efficient , for example inside the project there is a group of 10 classes that creates a curve view. I would like to know that anyone who copy this folder at any point, can use this in his own project. So should I locate this structure in one of those 10 files ? seems reasonable, but the other classes in MY project also need to use it. I can't find a reasonable place for it (as dumb as this question might be)

Comment: Put the files in a folder? Then you can just copy the folder and everything goes with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your struct in a separate file and document for each class you want to reuse that it depends on this struct. So basically you make your struct reusable as well.

The process of reusing your class becomes a little bit harder - you also have to include it’s *dependencies*. But that is just a fact of life, basically all software has dependencies. To make it easier to add some code dependency manages such as [Cocoapods](https://cocoapods.org), [Carthage](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage) or the [Swift Package Manager](https://swift.org/package-manager/) have been invented. With those you specify for each library what it depends on - so `ClassA` depends on `StructA`. In the project you want to use `ClassA` you specify only that dependency and the package manager installs all of it’s dependencies (and their dependencies and so on) together.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a separate library or framework which will contain all the reusable classes and structs.

Whenever you want to use the class `classA` or the struct `structA`, you can just import that library in the respective file.

Repeating the code is not recommended.